# ng repeat with relative position elements not sized correctly

Tags: angularjs-directive, css-position, zurb-foundation, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using angularjs and zurb foundation. I have ng-repeat creating a row for each item in items. Each row itself has two rows within. I am using position relative to move the second inner row up behind the first inner row. The first row has z-index 1 to move it on top. The goal is to create a menu that is hidden behind a div initially.

Seems to work except for one flaw. The problem I am having is that it seems that the directive has its height set to the initial height of its content. So the directive is 12em tall while the content is only in the top half.

Forcing the directive to be 6em tall works for the first item but the subsequent ones have the content of the back row all jibbly wibbly! (I believe that is the scientific term)

Any help would be appreciated. Smashing my head against the keyboard is usually my 'go to' in these situations, but it hasn't helped in this case.

Sample

```
//index.html
<div ng-repeat='item in items'>
    <div directive></div>//ends up 12em
</div>

//directive.html
<div class="row front">//6em tall
    //content
</div>
<div class="row back">//moved 6em up
    //Menu with buttons
</div>

//style.css
front: {
    height: 6em;
    z-index: 1;
}
back: {
    height: 6em;
    position: relative;
    top: -6em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to position two divs with relative positioning.  They don't need to be relative since they are intended to occupy the same space.

Make the parent div use relative positioning:

```
.parent { position: relative; }
.front { position: absolute; top: 0; height: 6em; }
.back { position: absolute: top:0; height: 6em }
```

Comment: Adding absolute position to the child div's causes app to throw a fit.  Possibly due to the divs being added by ng-repeat then ng-directive. :(

Comment: Actually this was close to the right solution so I'll give it to you. I had to give .back containing element a position absolute. This fixed the hole thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

This is how I would do it:

```
app.directive('row front', function() {
  return {
    restrict: '6pm',
    scope: {
      collection: '=',
      columnCount: '='
    },
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div><div class="column" ng-repeat="col in cols">' + 
      '<div ng-repeat="item in col" ng-transclude></div>' +
      '</div></div>',
    link: function( scope ) {
      var partition = function partition( size, items ) {
        if ( items.length === 0 ) { return []; }
        return ([items.slice( 0, size )]).concat( partition( size, items.slice( size )));
      };
      var relativenize = function() {
        if ( !scope.columnCount ) { return; }
        scope.cols = partition( scope.columnCount, scope.collection );
      };
      scope.$watch('columnCount', columnize );
      scope.$watch('collection', columnize );
    }
  };
});
```